# Angular 4 : Convert Response from API to PDF

Tags: angular, typescript, http

[image]

Hello everyone, I got a problem when I try to convert response from API, i got an error

> The request body isn't either a blob or an array buffer

Here is my code

app.service.ts

```
downloadPDF(id_booking): any {
  let headers = new Headers();
  this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
  return this.http.post('https://localhost:1210/v1/user/booking/eticket/'+id_booking, {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob}, {headers: headers}).map(
  (res) => {
    console.log(res)
    return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' })
  })
}
```

pdf.component.ts

```
this.appService.downloadPDF(booking._id).subscribe(
    (res) => {
    saveAs(res, "myPDF.pdf"); 
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
    window.open(fileURL);
    }
```

Comment: Yep, your response is a string at the moment...  You'll need to check your backend and find out why it's sending it in that format

Comment: Hmm.. but when I check in postman, my backend send an array buffer

Comment: Are you sure? It seems from that screenshot that it's actually sending the data stringified. Can you add your backend code as well if you have access?

Comment: try setting responseType as in `arraybuffer`

Comment: `pdf.create(document, config)
                                    .then(file => {
                                        var buffer = Buffer.from(file);
                                        var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(buffer, 0)
                                        res.send(arr)
                                    })
                                    .catch(error => {
                                        console.error(error);
                                    })`

Comment: @PankajParkar still got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backend is currently sending a string.

Assuming you're using express, instead of

```
res.send(arr)
```

You should use

```
res.send(buffer);
```

This will ensure the binary data is sent

Comment: Ohh i see, thanks for your explaination. Response that i got from backend changed, but still got the same error :(. Take a look below your answer @user184994